# Javascript tidying up procedural code - use a framework or browserify

Tags: jquery, frameworks, code-organization

I have a bit of javascript on every page of a 5 page site, some interactions (hamburger menu and other bits like an ajax call to pull in an xml file and a bit of google maps js.

At the moment it is just bundled up in a big js file. It woks fine but can't help but think this is a bit messy.The functions are all a bit disjointed and apply to different pages, what is a good way to group it all in an app? I have looked at either a framework or this

https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/